# Adding relative layout background drawable for undetermined layout size - Center Crop

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a background drawable to a relative layout. At first, I tried setting the background of the relative layout itself using

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImage);
```

Then after that I tried creating an image view and adding it to my relative layout first with this code :

```
ImageView backgroundImage = new ImageView(view.getContext());
backgroundImage.setImageResource(myImage);
backgroundImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

relativeLayout.addView(backgroundImage);
```

The problem is..its expanding my relativeLayout to the height of backgroundImage in both cases.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to set the background image to the size of the relative layout after all the children have been added so that there is no stretching and expanding past the relative layout height if there was no background image at all.

I also tried passing

```
public int getHeightOfView(View contentView) {
    contentView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    return contentView.getMeasuredHeight();
}

public int getWidthOfView(View contentView) {
    contentView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    return contentView.getMeasuredWidth();
}

int containerWidth = getWidthOfView(relativeLayout);
int containerHeight = getHeightOfView(relativeLayout);
```

For the ending result, I'm looking to set a background drawable to a relative layout programmatically with parameters that do not exceed the relative layouts height and width as if there were no background(after the view is populated with all the other children).

Each view that is populated has undetermined heights and widths. I need to maintain aspect ratio regardless if it center crops the image, that is no concern.

Comment: What is the size of your image?

Comment: @Athira it is roughly 1k squared.